# Eclipse - Data Driven Framework - Error Shown

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

[image][image][image]I have written a data driven framework Java program using below 2 classes. Inthis prgram am trying to log into system by taking login ids from external excel file.

1. DDF_ExcelClass - library java class to take data from external excel 
   file and will be called in SnapDealLogin_2
2. SnapDealLogin_2 - datadrivenframework java program which is failed. In 
   this class am taking login data from external excel file using 
   DDF_ExcelClass.

The error message shown are java.lang.RuntimeException: and 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Please note if login ids are given inside the program (not taking from external excel file) then SnapDealLogin_2 works good. failing when try to 
take login ids from excel file.
I have tried to identify the cause of fail but could not. please help.

```java
// Data Driver Framework - Excel Class stored as Library to reuse

package datadrivenframework;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class DDF_ExcelClass{

XSSFWorkbook Snap_WB;
XSSFSheet Snap_Sheet;

// NAVIGATING TO THE EXCEL FILE 
public DDF_ExcelClass(String Path) throws Exception{
File Snap_Excel = new File(Path);
FileInputStream Snap_Input = new FileInputStream(Snap_Excel);
Snap_WB = new XSSFWorkbook(Snap_Input);
Snap_WB.close();
}

// NAVIGATING TO THE EXCEL SHEET AND GETTING THE CELL VALUE THEN RETURNING THE SAME
public String Snap_ok(int SheetIndex, int Row, int Column){
Snap_Sheet  = Snap_WB.getSheetAt(SheetIndex);
String Snap_DataR = Snap_Sheet.getRow(Row).getCell(Column).getStringCellValue();
//System.out.println("THE VALUE IN THE ROW  " + Row + "  IS  " + Snap_DataR);
return Snap_DataR;
}
// FINDING THE TOTAL ROW COUNT IN THE DATA SHEET AND RETURNING THE SAME
public int filerowcount(int SheetID){
int rowcount = Snap_WB.getSheetAt(SheetID).getLastRowNum();
    //rowcount = rowcount+1;

return rowcount;

}
}
```

This is a simple data driver framework program where data is taken from external excel file

```java
package datadrivenframework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import datadrivenframework.DDF_ExcelClass;


public class SnapDealLogin_2 {

    @Test(dataProvider = "ABN") // declaring that @ Test annotation should get value from dataProvider annotation named "ABN" to proceed further

    public void Snap_Login(String UserID) throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\hp\\workspace\\Selenium\\browser\\chromedriver.exe"); // declaring the location of Chromedriver
    WebDriver Snap = new ChromeDriver(); // initializing webdriver Snap as ChromeDriver
    Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // adding implicit wait
    Snap.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/");// entering snapdeal web  url
    Thread.sleep(3000);// adding sleep
    Snap.manage().window().maximize(); // maximizing the browser
    Thread.sleep(2000);// adding sleep
    Snap.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sdHeader']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[1]")).click();// clicking Sign-On button
    Snap.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@href='https://www.snapdeal.com/login']")).click(); // Clicking Login button
    Snap.switchTo().frame("loginIframe"); // Switching the webdriver control to new frame "Loginframe"
    Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);// adding implicit wait
    Snap.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(UserID); // entering User id
    Snap.findElement(By.id("checkUser")).click(); //clicking "Continue"button
    Snap.quit(); // closing the window
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "ABN") // adding annotation as DataProvider and naming it as "ABN"
        public Object [][] Snap_DP() throws Exception{
        DDF_ExcelClass DEC = new DDF_ExcelClass("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\User_Credentials.xlsx");
        int rowcount = DEC.filerowcount(0);
        Object[][] xlobject = new Object[rowcount][1];
        for(int I = 0; I<=rowcount; I++){
        xlobject[I][0] = DEC.Snap_ok(0, I, 0);
        }
        return xlobject;
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you think what `Snap_WB.close();` is doing? Hints: `XSSFWorkbook extends POIXMLDocument`: [POIXMLDocument.close](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#close()).

Comment: @ Axel, hey thanks for your reply but could not understand what you mean? actually the program alerts that Snap_WB is not closed so have closed the same. please clarify, what went wrong?

Comment: After closing the workbook you cannot get sheets from it. Where exactly (in what code line)  what exact error (stack trace please!) is thrown?

Comment: @ Axel, have attached error screenshots. please refer and advise.

Comment: If code line 43 in `SnapDealLogin_2.java` is `xlobject[I][0] = DEC.Snap_ok(0, I, 0);`, then `I` is 5 but `xlobject[5][0] `, which is the sixth array item (0,1,2,3,4,5), is out of bounds. So your `Object[rowcount][1]` is dimensioned too small.

Comment: @ Axel, thank you so much dude, the program runs good now. got the logic you explained. have observed a behavior. attached the excel file from which i am pulling data into the program. so what happens is if give data as only numbers like 9999,444, etc am getting below error message

Comment: @ Axel, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell and error shown in drivenframework.DDF_ExcelClass.Snap_ok(DDF_ExcelClass.java:24) & drivenframework.SnapDealLogin_2.Snap_DP(SnapDealLogin_2.java:43).if i change the data to string like AAA, BBB etc  the program works. What i guess is in DDF_EXCELClass am saving the cell value as String as below String Snap_DataR = Snap_Sheet.getRow(Row).getCell(Column).getStringCellValue(); so if try to pull numbers, the above error shown. so how to handle this scenario which i mean, like to numbers from excel. please help.